# How to play video using FFmpeg on Ubuntu?

Tags: ffmpeg

I tried to install FFmpeg on my Ubuntu 15.

When I try to play video like this:

```
./ffplay video.mp4
```

It shows me that:

```
bash :./ffplay: no such file or directory
```

How can I fix this problem please?

Comment: How did you try to install `ffmpeg`?

Comment: just remove the space between ff and play => `ffplay`

Answer (score 13):

First you have to install `ffmpeg`.

Open a terminal and execute :

```
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
```

Navigate to the folder containing the video file and execute :

```
ffplay <video-file-name-including-the-file-extension>
```

Or open Nautilus file manager, right-click the folder containing the video file, open in terminal ...

Examples (one with spaces in the file name and one without) :

```
ffplay Type-C-Hypervisors.mp4

ffplay "OpenStack for Everybody.mp4"
```

Comment: when i execute this command tell <sudo apt-get install ffmpeg >                         ffmpeg is already the newest version .. and i try to play video from link .. i dont have that video on my folders....

Comment: @ldeveloper : This means that you already have ffmpeg installed. What do you mean with link ? Examples in the answer are videos that are on my PC ... so you of course have to take your video files and folders. :)

Comment: no , if i want play this video .                                                                     ./ffplay http://skyiptv.ddns.net:8000/live/batman/batman/400.ts

Comment: @ldeveloper : Here you can find some more information about video streaming with ffmpeg / ffplay -> https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/StreamingGuide - but this is not the "normal" way of using ffmpeg / ffplay ... :)

Comment: @cl-netbox Unfortunately, that guide is a mess (it's written by one well-intentioned, yet scatterbrained guy and has received no cleanup), and it about encoding for streaming, not playback. I think it will simply confuse the OP.

Comment: @ldeveloper That link returns "404 Not Found", but perhaps it is not supposed to be a http link. You need to provide the [input protocol](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html), such as `http://sykiptv...`, `rtp://sykiptv...`, `rtsp://sykiptv...`, etc. Perhaps VLC would be an easier player for you to use than `ffplay`.

Answer (score 4):

Your command `./ffplay` tries to run `ffplay` from the current directory ("`.`"). Since the `ffmpeg` package installs `ffplay` in `/usr/bin`, and not in your current directory, `./ffplay` cannot find the program to execute.

Use `ffplay video.mp4` (remove the "`./`"), and let your shell find the executable using `$PATH`.